# the npm start command is not working and showing an error of deprecated function of mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an `express` and `angular` project. I will show you the steps, so you can see if the problem is a missing command or no:

1. I started with installing express globally: `npm install -g express`
2. Then I created my express project: `express --view=hbs project_name`
3. I installed the dependencies: `npm install`
4. I installed all angular 4 required dependencies:

`npm install --save @angular/cli@latest`

`npm install --save @angular/core @angular/common @angular/http @angular/router @angular/compiler @angular/compiler-cli @angular/platform-browser @angular/animations @angular/platform-server ...`

5. I installed mongodb and mongoose: `npm install --save mongoose`

Now, I tried to run the command `npm start`, and I've got the following error:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok 1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node.exe', 1 verbose cli
>   'C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'start' ] 2 info using npm@5.5.1 3 info using
>   node@v6.9.4 4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
>   5 info lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~prestart:
>   udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 6 info lifecycle
>   udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start: udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 7
>   verbose lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in
>   lifecycle true 8 verbose lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start:
>   PATH:
>   C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\pc\dentist\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Fingerprint
>   Manager Pro\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Lenovo;C:\ProgramData\Lenovo\ReadyApps;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm 9 verbose lifecycle
>   udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\pc\dentist 10 silly
>   lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node
>   ./bin/www' ] 11 silly lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start:
>   Returned: code: 1  signal: null 12 info lifecycle
>   udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script 13
>   verbose stack Error: udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 start: `node
>   ./bin/www` 13 verbose stack Exit status 1 13 verbose stack     at
>   EventEmitter.
>   (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   ChildProcess.
>   (C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>   13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) 13 verbose stack
>   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7) 13 verbose stack     at
>   maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16) 13 verbose stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
>   14 verbose pkgid udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 15 verbose cwd
>   C:\Users\pc\dentist 16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601 17 verbose argv
>   "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "start" 18 verbose node v6.9.4 19 verbose npm  v5.5.1 20 error code
>   ELIFECYCLE 21 error errno 1 22 error udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0
>   start: `node ./bin/www` 22 error Exit status 1 23 error Failed at the
>   udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 start script. 23 error This is probably
>   not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above. 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Try executing `node ./bin/www` directly in app's directory and see if this gives you more useable information.

Comment: Firstly, what does npm start do in your package.json? check the scripts section. Secondly, you might want to use yarn instead of npm install since it is good at resolving issues with package dependencies